# How to marshal xml to a jaxb wrapper class?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
<myresponse>
    <field1></field1>
    <field2></field2>
    //...
</myresponse>

@XmlRootElement(name = "myresponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyResponse {
    //fields
}
```

The following would work fine:
`JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyResponse.class);`

Problem: I'd like to create a wrapper class around that response, and marshall it into this new class. But how, if the `XML` structure remains the same?

```
public class CustomResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "myresponse")
    private MyResponse myresponse;

    //some more DTO fields or bean logic
}
```

`JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomResponse.class);`

How can I tell `jaxb` to actually map anything from the xml response into the `@XmlElement(name = "myresponse")` object, if possible?

Sidenote: I have no control of the `xml` received.

Comment: A strange proposition indeed. All you need to do on marshalling is to take the myResponse from the CustomResponse and marshal that, and on unmarshalling, unmarshall and wrap it into a CustomResponse - all easily done in Java code without much ado.

Comment: I need this for a spring `RestTemplate` method call where I could only pass `CustomReponse.class`, thus I have to find a way where the xml as is could be marshalled into this class.